# How to start slack chat with user by channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack-api

I know that we have link to chat with user like this:

```
slack://channel?id=<CHANNEL-ID>&team=<TEAM-ID>
```

But I have just user's channel like `@mmike` and no `ID` of user in Slack.

How to write link with `@channel` of user?

Comment: The syntax is `slack://user?team={TEAM_ID}&id={USER_ID}`, but you still need to provide an id as detailed [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after tons of searching I founded the solution for this case:

```
slack://user?team=#{TEAM_ID}&id=#{user.slack_id}
```

For this case I got user's id's from Slack...